# Why is "arteria" sometimes accentuated?

Tags: acentuación

I have seen both *arteria* with and without an accent (*arteria* & *artería*). Why is it so? Is there any difference?

Examples of use for *artería*:

> Esto es el chorro de una **artería** —dijo en voz baja—.
>
> ---
>
> El revés descargado en el lado del cuello, en la **artería** carótida, ahogó el chillido...
>
> ([Source](https://www.foboko.com/diccionario-frases/espanol/arter%C3%ADa))

Example for *arteria*:

> La **arteria** es un conducto cuya función es llevar la sangre desde el corazón hasta las diferentes partes de nuestro cuerpo.
>
> ([Source](http://www.definicionabc.com/salud/arteria.php))

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Could you please add some examples of usage for both words? It seems that both "[arteria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3qKa7My)" and "[artería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3qOx5mN)" exist in the dictionary, but with different meanings.

Answer (score 5):

Every use of *arteria* in your examples must be written without the *tilde*, as the meaning is always

> **[arteria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3qKa7My)**
>
> Del lat. *arterĭa*, y este del gr. *ἀρτηρία artēría* 'vaso sanguíneo'.
>
> 1. f. Cada uno de los vasos que llevan la sangre desde el corazón a las distintas partes del cuerpo.

There is the possibility of writing *artería*, with the *tilde*, but then the meaning would change to

> **[artería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3qOx5mN)**
>
> De *artero*.
>
> 1. f. peyor. Amaño, astucia que se emplea para algún fin.

Here you have an example of *artería*:

> *Cuando la ira y la burla se aplacaron en él, le empezó el cansancio de sí mismo, y aquella artería para percibirlo todo, para rastrear los fallos, llegar aviesamente, implacablemente a la raíz última de las cosas.*
>
> Elena Quiroga, "La careta", 1955 (Spain)